# Reshape maintaining N samples in each row

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

I have already figured it how to do it but I want to check if there is a more efficient method.

What I want is to reshape a vector and keep samples 0 to 7 in the first row, then samples 8 to 15 in the second row, etc.

Here is an example of the output,

```
array([[   0,    1,    2, ..., 1221, 1222, 1223],
       [   8,    9,   10, ..., 1229, 1230, 1231],
       [  16,   17,   18, ..., 1237, 1238, 1239],
       ...,
       [  40,   41,   42, ..., 1261, 1262, 1263],
       [  48,   49,   50, ..., 1269, 1270, 1271],
       [  56,   57,   58, ..., 1277, 1278, 1279]])
```

With the input data looking something like,

```
array([   0,    1,    2, ..., 1277, 1278, 1279])
```

Is there a more efficient way other than,

```
data = np.arange(0, 128*10)

# Reshape for S/H
temp = data.reshape(8*8, -1, order='F')
out = np.zeros((8, int(len(data)/8)))
for idx in range(0, 8):
    out[idx] = temp[idx*8: idx*8+8, :].ravel(order = 'F')
```

Comment: btw is this what you want? `np.column_stack(data.reshape(-1,8,8))`?

Comment: @AkshaySehgal That (or the equivalent `np.hstack(data.reshape(-1,8,8))`) is probably the simplest solution. You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for my first answer I misread the question.

Here is a solution base on pure numpy transposition and reshaping:

```py
np.transpose( data.reshape(8, 8, -1, order='F'), (1,2,0)).reshape(8,-1)
```

Benchmarking against solutions herebelow gives:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One idea could be to break the `data` matrix into 64x1 vectors, reshape those vectors in 8x8 blocks, and concatenate the blocks:

```
data = np.arange(0, 128*10)

rows=8
columns=8
block_size=rows*columns

M=[data[block_size*i:block_size*(i+1)].reshape(rows,columns) for i in range(int(len(data)/block_size))]
np.concatenate((M),axis=1)
```

The output:

```
array([[   0,    1,    2, ..., 1221, 1222, 1223],
       [   8,    9,   10, ..., 1229, 1230, 1231],
       [  16,   17,   18, ..., 1237, 1238, 1239],
       ...,
       [  40,   41,   42, ..., 1261, 1262, 1263],
       [  48,   49,   50, ..., 1269, 1270, 1271],
       [  56,   57,   58, ..., 1277, 1278, 1279]])
```

Answer (score 0):

We can split this problem into 3 steps.

1. Reshape the data using the `reshape` method to get our base number, `N`, per row. In this case, 8 per row. So, we'd get 0-7 in the first row, 8-15 in the second, etc.
2. Split the array into `N**2` chunks. Knowing the size of the array (and assuming it's equally divisible), we can use `np.split` to split the array into the desired number of elements, determined by the total number of elements divided by `N**2`.
3. Finally, we can stack them all together using `np.hstack` to get the desired result.

In named steps:

```py
import numpy as np

data = np.arange(0, 128*10)

N = 8
step1 = data.reshape(-1, N)
step2 = np.split(step1, data.size/N**2)
step3 = np.hstack(step2)
```

All together:

```py
import numpy as np

data = np.arange(0, 128*10)

N = 8
out = np.hstack(np.split(data.reshape(-1, N), data.size/N**2))
```

Output:

```py
[[   0    1    2 ... 1221 1222 1223]
 [   8    9   10 ... 1229 1230 1231]
 [  16   17   18 ... 1237 1238 1239]
 ...
 [  40   41   42 ... 1261 1262 1263]
 [  48   49   50 ... 1269 1270 1271]
 [  56   57   58 ... 1277 1278 1279]]
```